# None of Index are in the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to describe a list values, but this error appears:

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['...'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

I've tried to search for whitespaces. I've set header to 0 and tried the `delim_whitespace=True` but there aren't any whitespace so I removed it.

```
%matplotlib inline
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('Dados.csv', sep=";", header=0)
x1 = df['com_proc'].values.tolist()
y = df['result_op'].values.tolist()

dados = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
dados

print("Estatísticas descritivas de y:")
dados[y].describe()
```

Dataframe shows as it should and makes me think that there's nothing wrong with it. The problem starts in the `dados[y].describe()`.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `dados[y].describe()`, `y` are values of `'result_op'`, unlikely they are column names of `df`.

Comment: Some of the values in `y` are not columns of `dados`. Plus `read_csv` gives a dataframe

Comment: Thank you, changing "y" to 'result_op' does work, however, why can't I use 'y' if I defined in the beginning?

Comment: If you want 'y' in your dataframe you need to add it. `df['y'] = df['result_op'].values.tolist()` or better yet `df['y'] = df['result_op']` .

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much :) 
Whats the difference between the df['y'] = df['result_op'].values.tolist().
and the y = df['result_op'].values.tolist()  ?

Comment: You're not adding 'y' to a DataFrame. You're creating a standalone pandas Series called 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

`df['result_op']` is pointing at the values in the column.
`DataFrame.describe()` or `Series.describe()` only works for those with valid names.
`dados[y]` is not returning anything, let alone `dados[y].describe()`